# Plugin for task not found (Grunt)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have next task for copy files, this test task and he changes in future, but he not running

```js
    pluginsCopy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'assets/js/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'assets/js/**/*',
            'assets/fonts/**/*',
            'index.html'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        },
          {
            expand: true,
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            src: [
              'package.json',
              'server/**/*'
            ]
          }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        dest: '.tmp/',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.css']
      }
    }
```

Register task:

```js
 grunt.registerTask('pluginsCp', function () {
    grunt.task.run(['pluginsCopy']);
  });
```

and run :
grunt pluginsCp

But I have next trouble:
jit-grunt: Plugin for the "pluginsCopy" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See [Static Mappings on GitHub](https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings).
Why grunt search plugin for my task?

Comment: Just because you name a config `pluginsCopy` doesn't mean that Grunt will know how to execute that config.  You need to create an actual task.